# PhoneGap push notification is not working when I change the Target SDK Version

Tags: phonegap-pushplugin

I have updated my Eclipse Android SDK to 24.1 version. After updating the Eclipse the push notification not received from gcm. I have added the new Google play services lib to my app. But the registration ID is not received from gcm. But when it was in last version of SDK the push notification process of gcm was working fine.